# Download a file within a listview nested in an UpdatePanel?

Tags: gridview, listview, updatepanel, download

How can you download a file from within a listview (or gridview) that is nested within an UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0):

You mean upload?  Can you just embed the [FileUpload control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) in a template field (in the case of a GridView, not sure about ListView)?

Or are you already doing this and having problems?  Could you be a little more specific?